# why this part of a statement is not in the hypothesis

Tags: formal-proofs

The question basically is

> For each of the following problems, identify the **hypothesis** (what you
>   can assume is true) and the **conclusion** (what you are trying to show is
>   true).
>
> Let $f(x) = 2^{-x}$ for any real number $x$. Then $f(x) = x$ for some real number $x$ with $0 \leq x \leq 1$

My solution is

**Hypothesis**: $f(x) = 2^{-x}$ for any real number $x$ with $0 \leq x \leq 1$.

**Conclusion:** $f(x) = x$ for some real number $x$.

My answer matches the book's answer expect that in the book this "with $0 \leq x \leq 1$" is part of the conclusion not the hypothesis. **My question** is why the foregoing statement is part of the conclusion? I only suspect the word "some" in the conclusion. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hypothesis is that the function $f(x)=2^{-x}$ is defined for any real number. This implies that it is defined also for $0\le x\le 1$, but this is a consequence of the hypothesis.

The thesis or conclusion is that the function has a fixed point $x=f(x)$ **in the interval $0\le x\le 1$**. In this statement the position of the fixed point is part of the conclusion that we want to prove.

Answer (score 0):

The hypothesis should be "Let $f(x)=2^{-x}$ for any real number $x$." This is what is stated in the original context. They did not restrict the domain of $f$, so the domain of $f$ is the entire real line.